# EOF returns true even if i have a populated recordset at the first pos in ADO

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado

Im trying to get rows from the  columns in a recordset and then insert those in a table plain and simple.

The recordset is populated and i used .MoveFirst to start at the beginning of the rs, Still i get EOF true at the very start and it jumps out of the do while..

I have a similar function woorking but this one won't woork for some reason.

I can't figureout why... or how to fix this. Anny insight is welcome!

current Code ~

```
Public Function makeSäljare()
'Create rs
Dim rsData As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sql As String

'Select what should be included in the rs.
rsData.Open "SELECT Forhandler, Selger FROM data", _
CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
rsData.MoveFirst


MsgBox rsData.GetString

'Manipulate each row of the result column.
Do While Not rsData.EOF


sql = "INSERT INTO säljare (Partner_Namn, Namn ) VALUES ('" & rsData!forhandler & "','" & rsData!Selger & "');"
MsgBox sql
'DoCmd.SetWarnings (False)
DoCmd.RunSQL (sql)
'DoCmd.SetWarnings (True)


rsData.MoveNext
'If rsData.EOF Then Exit Do

Loop

rsData.Close

End Function
```

It jumps out at Do While Not rsData.EOF..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetString` leaves the recordset at `EOF`.  `MoveFirst` again before `Do While Not rsData.EOF`

```vb
rsData.MoveFirst
MsgBox rsData.GetString
rsData.MoveFirst ' <-- add this
'Manipulate each row of the result column.
Do While Not rsData.EOF
```

Comment: Thank you :) woorks perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try your code, but this logically means that the recordset is empty. 
Check carefully if the query you executed on the db is correct.

In Access, use DAO instead of ADO and try this:

```
Set db = CurrentDb
set rsData = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT Forhandler, Selger FROM data", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: It was the problem HansUp Mentioned, When i check if i have something in my rs with the .getString method it puts the rs at EOF after i call the .MoveFirst. A stupid mistake on my part hehe , thanks for the imput tho!