# EOF value is always true even if there is record returned from VBA SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, eof

I am querying my access table using VBA and writing the query result in excel.

EOF is always true but BOF is False - even if the record count is 1 or 14 or 100. What possibly would be wrong? I can see the record count more than zero. get string value has data in it. Due to this there is no data written in the destination sheet except for Headers. The headers are coming in fine.

List of things tried but result was still same:

1. Added Move last and Move first command
2. Tried all possible combinations of Cursor location, cursor type, lock type
3. Tried with execute command
4. Tried with different MS access table
5. Tried early and late binding techniques

Below is my query and link below is my how my record set looks after SQL open statement.

```
    Const MyConn = "Access DB location"
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    With con
      .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
      .Open MyConn
    End With

    QuerySql = "SELECT * FROM Store_Location"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open QuerySql, con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdUnknown
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst


    i = 0  
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Sheets("Search_Temp").Cells(1, i + 1) = rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i

    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs  


    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
```

While debugging this is what my record set looks like:

[image: Debugging]

Comment: Which line were you on when looking at `rs`?

Comment: ps. you've specified a sheet for the headers but not the record. i.e. try including:  `Sheets("Search_Temp").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs`

Comment: I was on rs.MoveFirst

Comment: Ah ok; why do you have `rs.MoveLast` and `rs.MoveFirst`?  I assume that was to get the record for debugging; is that right / have you tried running the command without those commands included? (Should work anyway, but can't see anything obvious wrong...).

Comment: ps. when you say "on" do you mean the breakpoint was on that line?  If so it makes sense; you'd just run MoveLast so you're at the end of file not the beginning.  Does it change once you step forwards past MoveFirst?

Comment: Yes i added those move first and move last based on inputs from some forum. coz somebody suggested  that using that command will help in recalculating the complete record counts and position will be corrected. only thing that changes is the get string value coz it is pointing the first and the last record. nothing else changes

Comment: What does the table look like?  One of the comments in the `CopyFromRecordset` doc is that OLE Objects aren't supported, and Access does allow `OLE Object` type columns.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copyfromrecordset-method-excel

Comment: Its a table with 17 columns. having 14 rows. I am using the same code when i am initializing my userform. is working perfectly fine. Only difference is i am not using SQL query but dumping the complete table there.

Comment: you don't check EOF in your code??  You're misunderstanding something.  Try displaying the value of EOF on each record.  On the last record EOF will be true even though it returns a record.

Comment: @ashleedawg - in my case EOF is true when i execute MoveFirst command. Is it normal? i was under belief that EOF should be false when movefirst command is executed.

Comment: Stick with the `movelast` + `movefirst` like you had it.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building on [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18744041/2127508), calling `getString` on a Recordset object has a side-effect of moving the recordset to EOF.

You don't call `getString` anywhere in your code but you've added a watch on `rs.getString` which is visible as the last entry in the Watches window. If you have a watch on `rs.getString` and you have a breakpoint in the code where `rs` is open then that breakpoint will cause the recordset to move to EOF.

Depending on where the breakpoint occurs, this might not cause any issues (e.g. if the recordset was already at EOF) but, in this case, it is moving the recordset to EOF before you have copied the data from the recordset.

To solve this issue, remove the watch on `rs.getString`. It's probably a bad idea in general to have items in the Watches window cause side effects. You could also avoid the issue by not having any breakpoints where the recordset is open but removing the watch entirely is more robust.

The issue of `getString` moving the recordset to EOF isn't mentioned in the [ADO documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getstring-method-ado) but it's easy to reproduce this effect.

It's uncommon for someone to include the entire list of watches they had set in their question but I'm not sure this question was answerable without that information

Comment: Thanks barrowc. This worked. i guess the watch on rs.getstring was causing the EOF to be true. i knew rs.string will mess with the cursor pointer but I never knew the code result wil get impacted even if you have a watch on rs.getstring. Now the EOF is geting set propely when i executed removing the watch on rs.getstring.